# Range over array index in templates

Tags: go

I understand you can use index inside range:

```
{{range $i, $e := .First}}$e - {{index $.Second $i}}{{end}}
```

From: [how to use index inside range in html/template to iterate through parallel arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16141467/how-to-use-index-inside-range-in-html-template-to-iterate-through-parallel-array)

How do I range over the index if it also contains an array?

Eg.

```
type a struct {
   Title []string
   Article [][]string
}
IndexTmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", a)
```

index.html

```
{{range $i, $a := .Title}}
  {{index $.Article $i}}  // Want to range over this.
{{end}}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. The "index" is an `int`. Can you show the relevant parts of the struct/slice definition that contains your data?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use a nested loop, just as you would if you were writing code.

Here's some code demonstrating that, [also available on the playground](http://play.golang.org/p/JFkGmjq8mY).

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "os"
)

type a struct {
    Title   []string
    Article [][]string
}

var data = &a{
    Title: []string{"One", "Two", "Three"},
    Article: [][]string{
        []string{"a", "b", "c"},
        []string{"d", "e"},
        []string{"f", "g", "h", "i"}},
}

var tmplSrc = `
{{range $i, $a := .Title}}
  Title: {{$a}}
  {{range $article := index $.Article $i}}
    Article: {{$article}}.
  {{end}}
{{end}}`

func main() {
    tmpl := template.Must(template.New("test").Parse(tmplSrc))
    tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, data)
}
```

Comment: wow thank you so much! I was trying different syntax for a while but missed out on adding `$article :=`.