# Golang/Revel template engine template with variable

Tags: go, revel

Is there a way to pass a variable that was iterated over into a Golang/Revel template?

For example, in "header.html", I have

```
{{range .templates}}
    {{template "something" .}}
{{end}}
```

How can I use current index from the array as an argument to template? I tried embedding another {{.}} as shown in the Revel examples, but that leads to a template compliation error. Would the variable be something like $i?

For example, iterating through in Revel is done like so

```
{{range .messages}}
    <p>{{.}}</p>
{{end}}
```

However, I read that the . means nil.... how does this work in Revel?

Comment: I think all the pieces are [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16141467/how-to-use-index-inside-range-in-html-template-to-iterate-through-parallel-array) but I don't have the opportunity to test them enough to be confident in answering. Essentially: iterate over a range with len(.templates) and use indexing to get the values

Comment: Is there a more idiomatic way to do so? I've updated hte question with the details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use the `range` built-in to get the index, and then pass it to the template like this:

```
{{range $i, $t := .templates}}
   {{template "Template.html" $i}}
{{end}}
```

So if the `templates` variable was defined like this:

```
templates := []string{"One", "Two"}
```

and `Template.html` contains:

```
This is from Template.html: {{ . }}<br>
```

Then the final output will be:

```
This is from Template.html: 0<br>
This is from Template.html: 1<br>
```

Comment: Close, but I want to specify the name of the template based on the items in the array, not arguments passed to a static template name. I've tried using a range, and just doing {{template $t .}} but it doesn't seem to like that

Comment: Oh, okay, I see. Well, Go templates require a static parameter for the first argument of `template`. So variables won't do, not without some hackery :) But there is a thread here that might help you, if you're set on it: https://github.com/revel/revel/issues/988